# Продолжить работу сервиса, когда приложение свернуто

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver, android-location

Я пишу приложение которое отслеживает геолокацию пользователя пока он добирается до местоположения.
Я использую service чтоб отслеживать гео и записываю в базу, далее отправляю на сервер.
Все работает отлично, но проблемы начинаются когда я сворачиваю приложение или блокирую экран или открываю другое приложение поверх моего. Я находил множество решений, но ни одно из них мне не помогло.

**Вот код service**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "Hello World";
    private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public MyLocationListener listener;
    public Location previousBestLocation = null;
    Context context;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        context = this;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground()
    {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        listener = new MyLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1 * 1000, 0, listener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1 * 1000, 0, listener);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);

        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        return null;
    }

    protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
        if (currentBestLocation == null) {
            // A new location is always better than no location
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
        long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
        boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
        boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

        // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
        // because the user has likely moved
        if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
            return true;
            // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
        } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
        int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
        boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
        boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
        boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

        // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
        boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
                currentBestLocation.getProvider());

        // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
        if (isMoreAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
            return true;
        } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
        if (provider1 == null) {
            return provider2 == null;
        }
        return provider1.equals(provider2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, BootBroadcast.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

        public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)
        {
            if(isBetterLocation(loc, previousBestLocation)) {
               Log.d("onLocationChanged GPS:", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()) + " | " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
                PersonalGPS lastLocation = new PersonalGPS(loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude(),new Date().toString(),helper.getCurruntTicket());

               //do something with lastlocation
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Log.d("onProviderDisabled:", provider.toString());
            PersonalGPS lastLocation = new PersonalGPS(0.0,0.0,new Date().toString(),helper.getCurruntTicket());
            //do something with lastlocation
        }


        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            //context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
            Log.d("onProviderEnabled:", provider.toString());
        }


        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Log.d("onStatusChanged:", provider.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

**Вот код BootBroadcast**

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, LocationService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**Вот код в manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    <service
            android:name=".service.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootBroadcast">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Вот код вызова**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            this.startForegroundService (new Intent (this, LocationService.class));
        } else {
            this.startService (new Intent (this, LocationService.class));
        }
```

Сейчас тут я уже внес изменения и советы которые находил на форумах, теперь после того как я сверну приложение - сервис работает примерно 6 секунд и прекращает работу. Когда я возобновляю работу - сервис начинает работать как нужно.

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать чтоб отправлялось в свернутом режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось изменение разрешения для местоположения на:

```
Allow all the time
```

Comment: При продолжительной фоновой работе не отключается?